# How to enable SDN on actual switch

Tags: sdn

How to enable SDN on actual switch ? I have successfully simulated the SDN using the mini-net ,but when I use the actual switch I am not able to control the flows into the switch and not able to ping the Hosts .
I am using ODL controller with Cisco 3650 switch .Does any one did it successfully ?

-Ajay

Comment: Add details in the question about what you have tried and what is not working

Answer (score 0):

Verifying Cisco Plug-in for OpenFlow

SUMMARY STEPS

1. `show openflow copyright`
2. `show openflow switch switch-id`
3. `show openflow switch switch-id controllers [ stats ]`
4. `show openflow switch switch ports`
5. `show openflow switch-id flows [ configured | controller | default | fixed | pending | pending-del ] [ brief | summary]`
6. `show openflow switch switch-id stats`
7. `show interfaces type number counter`
8. `show running-config | section openflow`
9. `show openflow hardware capabilities`

Example: Specifying a Route to a Controller Using a Physical Interface

```
Switch> enable
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
Switch(config-if)# no switchport
Switch(config-if)# ip address 10.0.1.4 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)# exit
Switch(config)# ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.6
Switch# copy running-config startup-config
Switch(config)# exit
```

Example: Specifying a Route to a Controller Using a Management Interface

```
Device> enable
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Switch(config-if)# no switchport
Switch(config-if)# ip address 10.0.1.4 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)# exit
Switch(config)# ip route vrf mgmtVrf 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.6
Switch# copy running-config startup-config
Switch(config)# exit
```

Example: Cisco Plug-In for OpenFlow Logical Switch Configuration (Default VRF)

```
Switch> enable
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# onep
Switch(config-onep)# exit

Switch(config)# openflow
Switch(config-ofa)# switch 1

! Specifies the pipeline that enables the IP Forwarding Table.
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# pipeline 1
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# tls trust-point local local-trustpoint-name remote remote-trustpoint-name
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# max-backoff 5
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# probe-interval 5
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# rate-limit packet-in 300 burst 50
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# controller ipv4 10.0.1.6 port 6323 security none
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# datapath-id 0x222

! Adding an interface to the Cisco Plug-In for OpenFlow logical switch.
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# of-port interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
Switch(config-ofa-switch)#end
Switch# copy running-config startup-config
```

Example: Configuring a Cisco Plug-In for OpenFlow Logical Switch (Management VRF)

```
Switch> enable
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# onep
Switch(config-onep)# exit

Switch(config)# openflow
Switch(config-ofa)# switch 1
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# pipeline 1

! Specifying a controller that is part of a VRF.
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# controller ipv4 10.0.1.6 port 6323 vrf mgmtVrf security none

! Adding an interface to the Cisco Plug-In for OpenFlow logical switch.
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# of-port interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
Switch(config-ofa-switch)# end
Switch# copy running-config startup-config
```

More detail [here: Cisco Plug-in for OpenFlow Configuration Guide for Catalyst 3850 and 3650 Series Switches](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/37e/b-openflow-37e-3850-and-3650/b-openflow-37e-3850_chapter_01.html)

Comment: Hi can I get you email Id so that I can contact you regarding the resolution ? Actually I did the configuration I am not able to control the flows from controller .

Comment: By default it configures interface as trunk and not as access .